# Merge two time series with offset?

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have two files with time series data, like this:

```
file_A.csv:
t,x,y,z
00:00:00,1,1,1
00:00:01,2,2,2
00:00:02,3,3,3
00:00:03,4,4,4

file_B.csv:
t,x,y,z
00:00:00,5,5,5
00:00:01,6,6,6
00:00:02,7,7,7
```

and would like to merge them in order to get:

```
t,x,y,z
00:00:00,1,1,1
00:00:01,2,2,2
00:00:02,3,3,3
00:00:03,4,4,4
00:00:04,5,5,5
00:00:05,6,6,6
00:00:06,7,7,7
```

Basically, I want to offset "t" of data set N+1 by the last value of "t" of data set N.

How can I do that? [combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns) is not what I want: it just merges the two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to guess some stuff in your question (exact format of time, are the times initially sorted, are the increments necessarily fixed), but here is the general idea.

Starting with the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_csv(StringIO('t,x,y,z\n00:00:00,1,1,1\n00:00:01,2,2,2\n00:00:02,3,3,3\n00:00:03,4,4,4'))
b = pd.read_csv(StringIO('t,x,y,z\n00:00:00,5,5,5\n00:00:01,6,6,6\n00:00:02,7,7,7'))
```

Convert to times and sort (possibly can skip the last part):

```
a.t = pd.to_datetime(a.t)
a.sort(columns=[a.t.name], inplace=True)
b.t = pd.to_datetime(b.t)
b.sort(columns=[b.t.name], inplace=True)
```

Increment each time in `b` by the difference between it and the first time in `b` + the last time in `a` plus 1 sec.

```
b.t = b.t - b.t[0] + a.t.values[-1] + np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Finally, concat:

```
pd.concat([a, b])
```

(Note that the times here are full `datetime`s now, i.e., with dates.)

Comment: This is enough to get me going. Thanks!